Maximum value for an function limited to points on the unit circle
I am hoping to find the maximum value for the function $\left(2^x \cdot 3^y\right)$, but limited to points on the unit circle $\left(x^2 + y^2 = 1\right)$.
I have found approximations,
$x=0.533, y=0.846$, function value $= 3.665$,
but I would like to be able to know how to express exact values, and this is beyond my math know-how.
I would also be interested in expanding to 3 dimensions for the function $(2^x \cdot 3^y \cdot 5^z)$, for points on a unit sphere $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1)$.
I have similarly found approximations
$x=0.335, y=0.531, z=0.778$; function value $= 7.911$,
but I would also like to be able to know how to express exact values.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Best,
Erik

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think it'll be useful to mention what relevant mathematical things you know and/or things you have tried to solve this mathematically, so that the answers you receive can be more targeted. For example, I think there's no point in someone providing an answer using Lagrange multiplier if you do not even know what derivative is.

In general, arbitrary powers are defined as their exponential representations.
$$2^x \ 3^y = e^{x \log 2} \ e^{ y \log 3} = e^{x \log 2 + y \log 3}$$
The unit circle is represented by its standard representation
$$x=\cos \phi , y = \sin \phi$$
So your function of interest is
$$\phi \mapsto e^{ \log 2 * \cos \phi +  \log 3 * \sin \phi} $$
Extremal values are determined by zeros of the derivative, that reproduces  the exponential times derivative of the exponent. The exponential has no zero except for an exponent of $-\infty$. Solve for the zero of the derivative of the exponent.
Analogously on the sphere you may use the exponential form with cylinder coordinates $$x=\sqrt{1-z^2}\  \cos \phi, y=\sqrt{1-z^2}\  \sin \phi$$
